# Shrinking and Expanding code blocks in Xcode 9

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Xcode 9 introduces a new text editor which is fine, but is there a way to but back feature with shrinking and expanding blocks of code as of Xcode 9.0 (9A235) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the cursor somewhere in the block and press <kbd>⌥⌘←</kbd>. That's much more convenient than the *old* way.